I have the following that works perfectly with numbers but I don't know how to get it to work with letters too
 jQuery('input[name="_tipo"], label input[name="_tipo"]').on('change', function() {
    var mask = (jQuery(this).val() == 'CPF') ? '00000000000' : '00000000000000';
    jQuery('input[name="user_login"]').mask(mask);
    
    var labelText = (jQuery(this).val() == 'CPF') ? 'Entre com seu CPF (login)' : 'Entre com seu CNPJ (login)';
    jQuery('input[name="user_login"]').closest('.jet-form-builder-row').find('.jet-form-builder__label-text').text(labelText);
});

I'm not sure where to look for a reference guide for this kind of thing. Any help would be much appreciated!

Found this in the docs:
/**
nonInput: elements we consider nonInput
dataMask: we mask data-mask elements by default
watchInputs: watch for dynamically added inputs by default
watchDataMask: by default we disabled the watcher for dynamically
added data-mask elements by default (performance reasons)
**/

$.jMaskGlobals = {
  maskElements: 'input,td,span,div',
  dataMaskAttr: '*[data-mask]',
  dataMask: true,
  watchInterval: 300,
  watchInputs: true,
  watchDataMask: false,
  byPassKeys: [9, 16, 17, 18, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 91],
  translation: {
    '0': {pattern: /\d/},
    '9': {pattern: /\d/, optional: true},
    '#': {pattern: /\d/, recursive: true},
    'A': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z0-9]/},
    'S': {pattern: /[a-zA-Z]/}
  }
};

Therefore replace all the 0s with As. (I also added a "translation" so called to make sure). I hope this works:
jQuery('input[name="_tipo"], label input[name="_tipo"]').on('change', function() {
  var mask = (jQuery(this).val() == 'CPF') ? 'AAA.AAA.AAA-AA' : 'AA.AAA.AAA/AAAA-AA';
  // jQuery('input[name="user_login"]').mask(mask);
  // or:
  jQuery('input[name="user_login")').mask(mask, {
    translation: {
      'A': {
        pattern: /[A-Za-z0-9]/
      }
    }
  })
})

